# cv::imencode to append buf

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a snippet in my application similar to this:

```
std::vector<int> const jpegParams{ CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 75 };
std::vector<uchar> out;
out.push_back(4);
out.push_back(5);
out.push_back(6);
out.push_back(7);
cv::imencode(".jpg", someMat, out, jpegParams);
```

Signature of `cv::imencode`:

```
CV_EXPORTS_W bool imencode( const string& ext, InputArray img,
                            CV_OUT vector<uchar>& buf,
                            const vector<int>& params=vector<int>());
```

I would like `cv::imencode` not to overwrite the beginning of `out` just to append to it. With its current behavior I have to copy away the generated JPG by four bytes in order to be able to write my special treatment to the beginning.

Do you know some workaround or another function that may help me?

Comment: Yeah, it was a bad advice so I remove my comments. Sorry about that. May I ask why you want to avoid to copy the data? What kind of time constraints do you have?

Comment: Avoidable copy of the entire encoded image slightly bothers me. From the point of view of the implementer of the `imencode`: appending would be just as easy and more universal. One could `clear()` the vector before passing it (or create it immediately before), the other could pass it otherwise prepared. But that's not how they figured and some time later that might affect the effective performance of my prog. There is no imminent risk of it currently. Also others may have this problem as I can imagine situations where this matters.